# Java concurrency - pass data to other waiting thread

Tags: java, concurrency

I have two components:

- The manager, on which `add(Data)` can be called. This will add some data to the manager.
- The clients, which can call `retrieve(predicate)` on the manager. A list of `Data` objects which match the given predicate are returned. If there is no such data, `retrieve` keeps waiting.

A typical blocking priority queue cannot be used here, since the client is not interested in every new object. Only those who are allowed by his requirements as defined in the predicate are useful for him.

How can this be implemented in Java? I could get it working with a `x.notifyAll()` call after each call to `add(Data)` in the manager, and a `x.wait()` in the `retrieve(predicates)` method. I was wondering if the `java.concurrent` package has more higher-level functionalities which can be used for this problem.

Comment: `BlockingQueue` can be a cheap and easy solution, just add some interface to it with loop that will discard all incoming elements unless they match predicate. (however there is a risk of it storing useless data, if you don't consume its contents fast enough)

Comment: Let's say new data is added to the blocking queue. But this data is not interesting for some client. How can that client keep waiting for new data?

Comment: This can't be very efficient, because your retrieve method would always first have to loop through all elements in the queue. It's better to filter on the predicate *before* putting it in one of a set of BlockingQueues, and then to `take` from the queue belonging to the predicate you want.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt, yeah, and even then we still have to know how many clients there are and keep queue for each one all the time. Also there it's even more complicated if we have to keep historical data and give it to new clients.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt Good idea, but this is not possible in my case. The predicates are not fixed and known in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an outline of something that may give you an idea. For simplicity I am going to assume that `predicates` and `data` are strings.

As you stated you do not know your `predicates` ahead of time so I would try to dynamically update and cache based on new incoming predicates.

**Manager**

```
public class Manager(){
    private Map<String, Set<String>> jobs = new HashMap<>():
    private Set<String> knownPredicates = new HasSet();
    private final static String GENERAL = "GENERAL_DATA";

    public void addJob(String data){
        Set<String> matchingPredicates = getMatchingPredicates(data);
        if(matchingPredicates.isEmpty()){
            updateJobs(GENERAL, data);
        } else {
            for(String predicate: matchingPredicates){
                updateJobs(GENERAL, data);
            }
        }

        synchronized(this){
            notifyAll();
        }
    }

    private Set<String> getMatchingPredicates(String data){
        Set<String> matchingPredicates = new HashSet<>();
        for(String knownPredicate: knownPredicates){
            // Check if the data matched the predicate. If so add it to the list
        }
        return matchingPredicates;
    }

    private void updateJobs(String predicate, String data){
        Set<String> dataList;
        if(jobs.containsKey(predicate)){
            dataList = jobs.get(predicate);
        } else {
            dataList = new HashSet<>();
        }
        dataList.add(data);
        jobs.put(predicate, dataList);
    }

    public synchronized List<String> retrieve(String predicate){
        Set<String> jobsToReturn;
        knownPredicates.add(predicate);
        if(jobs.containsKey(predicate)){
            jobsToReturn = jobs.remove(predicate); 
        }

        for(String unknownData: jobs.get()){
            //Check if unknownData matches the new predicate if it does add it to jobsToReturn
        }

        cleanupData(jobsToReturn);
        return jobsToReturn;
    }

    //Removes data that may match more than one predicate
    private static void cleanupData(Set<String> dataSet){
        for(String data: dataSet){
            for(Set <String> predicateSet: jobs.values()){
                predicateSet.remove(data);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Client**

```
public class Client() implements Runnable{
    private Manager managerRef;
    public Client(Manager m){
        managerRef = m;
    }

    public void run() {
        while(true){
            String predicate = //Get the predicate somehow
            Set<String> workToDo = managerRef.retrieve(predicate)
            if(workToDo.isEmpty()){
                synchornized(managerRef){
                    managerRef.wait();
                } 
            } else {
                //Do something
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The above is only a skeleton though. You would have to resolve some issue regarding clearing your known predicates etc. . .

Answer (score 0):

You might need to consider implementing predicate-based caching with the following behavior:

- If `'retrieve(predicate)'` method has never been called and `'add(Data)'` method is executed, a new Data object is simply added to the manager and cache remains empty.
- If `'retrieve(predicate)'` method is called, the client checks the cache for the requested predicate in order to retrieve references to the corresponding Data objects. If cache is empty or no match has been found, the system runs a search on the specified predicate against all Data objects in the manager and updates the cache. To improve the performance, if no match found, flag this up in the cache so that the subsequent queries for the same predicate are returned faster.
- If `'add(Data)'` method is called and cache isn't empty, the Data object being added is scanned for all predicates already in the cache and the matching objects are associated by a reference with the corresponding predicates in the cache.

Note as any caching mechanism, it will be slower at the start but will improve as more objects fill up the cache.